# unzip extract in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, extract, unzip

i am using below code to extract files as below, but i see additional folder being created, could some one please help me why extra folder is being created.

my file is as abc.zip which contains file sql.db,so ideally i need folder file as abc/sql.db but when i extract using below code i get folder as acb/abc/sql.db, why am i getting this extra folder being created

```
def unzip_artifact( local_directory, file_path ):
    fileName, ext = os.path.splitext( file_path )
    if ext == ".zip":
        print 'unzipping file ' + basename(fileName) + ext
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path) as zf:
                for member in zf.infolist():
                        # Path traversal defense copied from
                        # http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/http/server.py#l789
                        words = member.filename.split('/')
                        path = local_directory
                        for word in words[:-1]:
                            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
                            head, word = os.path.split(word)
                            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir, ''): continue
                            path = os.path.join(path, word)             
                        zf.extract(member, path)

        except zipfile.error, e:
            print "Bad zipfile: %s" % (e)
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally unzipping a file will create directories for you.  So if the .zip file has the abc directory in it, your building of path is what is getting in the way.  Try:

```
def unzip_artifact( local_directory, file_path ):
    fileName, ext = os.path.splitext( file_path )
    if ext == ".zip":
        print 'unzipping file ' + basename(fileName) + ext
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path) as zf:
                for member in zf.infolist():
                        # Path traversal defense copied from
                        # http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/http/server.py#l789
                        zf.extract(member, local_directory)
        except zipfile.error, e:
            print "Bad zipfile: %s" % (e)
        return
```

Or better yet just use extractall:

```
def unzip_artifact( local_directory, file_path ):
    fileName, ext = os.path.splitext( file_path )
    if ext == ".zip":
        print 'unzipping file ' + basename(fileName) + ext
        try:
            zipfile.ZipFile(file_path).extractall(local_directory)
        except zipfile.error, e:
            print "Bad zipfile: %s" % (e)
        return
```

Comment: thanks cforbish, that works great, could you guide me which ones is better using zf.extract or extract all and why, i am dealing with zip files of size over 2GB , so just wanted to be sure that it doesn't fail

Comment: @sandeep, if you only want to extract files that are under a certain size, you can use the first method and `member.file_size` to test the file size.

Comment: Thanks Cforbish, is there a way to omit the first root folder of the completely and extract from one level under it, All my zip files contain one root folder and many folders under it, lets say abc.zip has abc/123,456,789 folders, i just want the 123,456,789 folders unzipped by omiting the root abc folder, could i do that